# Refresh page link clicked automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I would like so reference like when I enter into a page, suddenly a link should be clicked. Is it possible to perform that
Tried 1

```
     <script>
          document.onload = function(){
           document.getElementById('overviewOfSolarSystem').click();
      }
     </script>
```

Tried 2
This the code i tried but not working

```
     <script>
          document.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById('javascript:setPage(2)').click();
         }
     </script>
```

Below is the link in the body

```
     <a id="overviewOfSolarSystem;" style="color:#ffbc00;" href="javascript:setPage(2)">(Learn More)</a>
```

Comment: the id is "overviewOfSolarSystem", not "javascript:setPag(2)"

Comment: sorry, i put that. I edited question i wrong put tried 1 and tried 2 same. Tried 1 is the overviewOfSolarSystem was my id

Comment: Rather than simulating a click on the link, you could (probably) just _call_ `setPage(2)` where you have the code to simulate the click.

Comment: how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

Add this just before your `</body>`:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('overviewOfSolarSystem');
    element.click()
</script>
```

Comment: Just altered the answer.

Comment: how it works is when i refresh a page, the link should be clicked which will be directed as in the javascript of page 2 of the book.

Answer (score 0):

add to your html

```
<script>   
$(function(){
        $("#yourLinkIdHere").click();
    });
</script>
```

Explaining:

the $(function(){}); is an aliais for the document.ready javascript event. this code just tells javascript to click the element that has the id "yourLinkIdHere" when the page finishes loading

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript, as the question:

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('overviewOfSolarSystem\\;').click();
}
```

If you use jQuery, the answer above's best.

EDIT: Edited my answer as you edited the question :D

Comment: Fixed it, window.onload or document.onload, the best that fits for you.

Comment: how it works is when i refresh a page, the link should be clicked which will be directed as in the javascript of page 2 of the book.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //Html File
     <a class="refresh_link" href="javascript:void(0)">click to Refresh the Page</a>
        //Js Code
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".refresh_link").click(function() {
            window.location = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer for this question.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com"
    </script>
```